# Python -m venv stopped opening virtual environment in Visual Studio Code and gives out no error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Tried to start my virtual env like I have previously, and this happened

```
PS C:\Users\QPBSy\Documents\DEV> Python -m venv .
PS C:\Users\QPBSy\Documents\DEV>
```

No color indicater to show the environment started. I notice to the left in the terminal it will go from powershell to python and then right before the second line appears after typing Python -m venv . python will revert to powershell.

Tried creating a new virtual environment with Python-m venv venv, it does the same process. Changes terminal to python, then reverts back to powershell and shows the next line no errors.

When I try to implement .\Scripts\Activate after attempting to start the environment as normal this is what I get
.\Scripts\Actvivate :

```
The term '.\Scripts\Actvivate' is not recognized as the 
name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling   
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try    
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\Scripts\Actvivate
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\Scripts\Actvivate:String) [], Co  
   mmandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  IIRC, ```python -m venv .``` just creates the virtualenv.  You need to do a ```.\scripts\activate``` to activate the virtualenv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `python -m venv .` to create a virtual environment, then use `.\scripts\activate` to activate the virtual environment.

Note the capitalization. `.\scripts\activate` is not `.\Scripts\Activate`.

It is recommended that you use the `py -3 -m venv .venv` command to create a virtual environment, which will generate a `venv` folder,
When you create a virtual environment, VS Code prompts you to set it as the default for the workspace folder. If checked, the environment will be automatically activated when you open a new terminal.

[image]

You can also activate the environment using the `.venv\scripts\activate` command.
When you use a virtual environment, there will be a status prompt in the VS Code status bar.

[image]

Hope this helps you.